# OpenVPN setup on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

I am having trouble setting up my computer to use a VPN in a specific way.

My desktop has 4 ethernet ports (Intel PCI-E Addon Card) and im running windows 10. I only have 2 or the 4 ethernet ports plugged in and they are setup for static IP. I want to setup one port be VPN to a vpn service i subscribe to and the other just to be regular ethernet port. I will be using the latest openvpn version.

So far i have read about binding openvpn to a specific IP only and not a specific interface but if my interfaces are static then binding it to a ip is no big deal with the --local option. I am assuming i would put that option in the .opvpn file that i get from my VPN provider.

I want a few programs to use the VPN port. I play games and watch netflix and those dont play very well with a VPN. So i was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to get this done. I have been searching online for answers but it seems the answers that i read arent really for the type of setup i want. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I don’t see how that extra port on your NIC is related to OpenVPN at all. It connects like any other program does. If you believe it should use a different gateway, you must adjust the routing table.

Comment: I have never used VPN like this so I am a total noob to the setup.. I figured I needed another port to run this kind of setup